# How does temperature compensation work for strain gauge in wheatstone bridge

Tags: resistors, resistance, measurement, wheatstone-bridge, strain-gage

Wheatstone bridge is used for temperature compensation for strain gauges

[image]

If 2 strain gauges are connected like this figure. Due to temperature variation; the resistance Rg will change in the same way.

Lets say; the bridge is balanced at start.
R1/R2 = (RG+DeltaR)/(RG-DeltaR)

If strain gauge resistance increases due to temperature:
R1/R2 = (RG+DeltaR+RT)/(RG-DeltaR+RT)

How does this compensation work?

(RG+DeltaR+RT)/(RG-DeltaR+RT) is not the same as (RG+DeltaR)/(RG-DeltaR)

So gets the bridge unbalanced???

Comment: You would need also R1 and R2 to be strain gauges.

Comment: It's said, that half or full bridge includes temperature compensation. This is half bridge.

Comment: Where is this said?

Comment: But first of all make your equations in the form like used in this forum. At least put the brackets, since the math, rules say multiplication and division have a priority over subtraction and addition.

Comment: http://elektron.pol.lublin.pl/elekp/ap_notes/NI_AN078_Strain_Gauge_Meas.pdf - Page 3-4

Comment: As said R1 and R2 are also strain gauges, called dummy gauges, read the description.

Comment: By using two strain gauges in the bridge, the effect of temperature can be avoided. For example, Figure 5 illustrates a
strain gauge configuration where one gauge is active (RG + ∆R), and a second gauge is placed transverse to the applied
strain. Therefore, the strain has little effect on the second gauge, called the dummy gauge. However, any changes in
temperature will affect both gauges in the same way. Because the temperature changes are identical in the two gauges,
the ratio of their resistance does not change, the voltage VO does not change.

Comment: So two strain gauges is sufficient for temp compensation.

Answer (score 1):

A real 4 element strain gauge is designed to have compensation like this: -

[image]

As you should be able to see, the temperature compensation "modifies" the gain of "both paths" in the bridge because it is in series with the excitation voltage/current. That's how temperature compensation works on a real device whether it is full-bridge or half-bridged active elements.